# login into oscommerce admin panel via cURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl, admin, oscommerce

I am trying to login into oscommerce admin panel via cURL and PHP, I put already the right login and password in the post_array but I keep getting "Error: Invalid administrator login attempt." Am I sending the POST data and saving the cookies correctly?
Here is my code:

```
    <?php
$agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; tr; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)';
$username = 'PromptUsername';
$password = 'PromptPassword';
$URL =  'http://www.example.com/admin/login.php'; //'http://www.example.com/admin/categories.php?cPath=21';
$path1 = 'cookies/';
$post_array = array(  
'username'=>'usernAme',
'password'=>'passw0rd'
);
$authURL = $URL.'?action=process';

// Login here
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $authURL);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($path1.'cookies.txt') );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($path1.'cookies.txt'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_array));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$username:$password")."\r\n",
));
$debug = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
var_dump($debug);
$store = curl_exec ($ch);
var_dump($store);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding `\r\n` with the authorization header which upsetting the server. Just remove them.

```
"Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$username:$password"),
```